# InApp Purchase OSX - Worked in sandbox, App review claims didn't appear

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have weird problem, i have submitted first osx app,i have tested IAPS, which have have just copied from ios working code, with few little changes, for example receipt handling. Iaps works, 5-10s after click window with app store appeared and i was able to complete purchase over sandbox, but app review claims that didn't appeared any dialog after 3min.Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing any server-side checks for your own internal IP ranges before accepting sandbox purchases, are you?

Beyond that, it is possible that the app reviewers experienced a brief network outage or something.  Either that or your code failed to start the purchase correctly for some reason, such as an incorrect item identifier or something.

Comment: It worked perfectly on ios, and on osx sandbox. It just get receipt after purchase, send it to my server. If sandbox i just skip verification. If real proceed. It's confusing since they didn't even see Dialog with log in to appstore or confirm purchase.

Comment: The reason I ask is that I think Apple's app review team uses sandbox purchases when testing.